# Web3.js Batch Request Limit?

Tags: web3js, transactions, javascript, batch

I'm trying out `Batch Request` provided by `web3.js`. In the example below I want to test making 300 transactions but i get the error log displayed below. I'm trying to figure out the error log but it seems to me that there is some kind of limit. Does anyone know if that is the case?

`instance` is just my contract instance.

```js
async function multipleTx(
  TRANSACTIONS = 300,
  GAS_PRICE = 2000000000,
) {
  let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()

  await instance.methods
    .addSubmissionNoCheck(6, Math.round(Date.now() / 1000))
    .send({
      from: accounts[0],
      gasPrice: GAS_PRICE,
    }) // works

  var bookingBatch = new web3.BatchRequest()
  for (let i = 0; i < TRANSACTIONS; i++) {
    bookingBatch.add(
      instance.methods
        .addSubmissionNoCheck(6, Math.round(Date.now() / 1000))
        .send.request(
          { from: accounts[i], gasPrice: GAS_PRICE, value: 1 },
          bookingCallback
        )
    )
  }
  bookingBatch.execute() //throws error
}
multipleTx()
```

Error Log:

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: {}
    at Object.InvalidResponse (C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensar
bete\tqdt33\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\src\errors.js:42:16)
    at C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules
\web3-core-requestmanager\src\batch.js:61:60
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules
\web3-core-requestmanager\src\batch.js:54:12
    at C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules
\web3-core-requestmanager\src\index.js:166:20
    at C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules
\async\internal\map.js:32:9
    at C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules
\async\internal\once.js:12:16
    at iteratorCallback (C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbete\t
qdt33\node_modules\async\eachOf.js:58:13)
    at C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules
\async\internal\onlyOnce.js:12:16
    at C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules
\async\internal\map.js:29:13
    at C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules
\@truffle\hdwallet-provider\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\index.js:157:9
    at C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules
\async\internal\once.js:12:16
    at replenish (C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\n
ode_modules\async\internal\eachOfLimit.js:61:25)
    at C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules
\async\internal\eachOfLimit.js:71:9
    at eachLimit (C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\n
ode_modules\async\eachLimit.js:43:36)
    at C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules
\async\internal\doLimit.js:9:16
```

Comment: How and where do you call function `multipleTx`? Do you `await` for it to complete, or do you resolve the promise that it returns in any other manner? BTW, you probably wanna add `return await` before `bookingBatch.execute()`.

Comment: I just called `multipleTx` from the bottom of the file. I can update my post to show that. I tried `return await bookingBatch.execute()` same error occurs

Comment: Have you tried a "normal" transaction with your `web3` instance? The `Invalid JSON RPC response` error-message implies that you might be disconnected from the node.

Comment: @goodvibration yes i have and it works, i update my post to indicate this

Comment: BTW, I'm pretty sure that `BatchRequest` is for RPCs (`.call`) only. You, on the other hand, are trying to use it for transactions (`.send`).

Comment: @goodvibration That's weird because i was able to make 10 `send` RPCs on another of my smart contract functions using batch request. but when i upped it to 300 i got the same error. However i have now found out that Infura imposes a rate limit of 10 JSONRPC requests/second. So this is definitely a problem for me

Comment: @Conviley Why do you use batch requests? As said by goodvibration it is mostly used to make several queries at the same time.

Comment: @Ismael because i need it for my research and i've been looking at ways to send a couple of hundreds of tx but i'm running into problem after problem. I asked a similar question in the past where i think you actually suspected infura but then i thought i fixed it, turns out i didn't. Today i found out that infura not only impose a request limit but also a rate limit. Right now i'm looking at running my own ethereum node and i am currently syncing a parity node with ropsten. Hopefully i'll be able to use it and run my tests at the scale i need them to run in.

Comment: @Conviley Batch requests will not help you with making hundred of transactions. A note for web3 v0.20 applies here _Note Batch requests are not faster! In fact making many requests at once will in some cases be faster, as requests are processed asynchronously. Batch requests are mainly useful to ensure the serial processing of requests._ https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#batch-requests

Comment: I'll suggest to use a private testnet, public testnet might not be ideal to measure raw performance.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks for the link! Since I set up my own ethereum node i will be dropping trying to implement batch requests. The reason i want to test on ropsten is to get as close to mainnet performance as possible without actually testing on mainnet.

Answer (score 1):

Web3js doesn't have the request limit, but the node, you communicate with, could have. Unfortunately, `web3js@1.*` doesn't give the errors thrown by the network or server in batch requests. I had a similar issue - the server has rate-limited my requests, but I didn't get a helpful message about the error. This issue seems not to be fixed in  `v1` - https://github.com/web3/web3.js/pull/5875

As a workaround, when the `InvalidResponse` error is returned for the BatchRequest, I switch to processing the requests by one with `web3.currentProvider.send(singleItem, cb)`, in the `callback` I get the error from the server, where all required details on backoff are specified, and I can  wait `X` time to continue with Requests.